# How do you forward Twilio calls to different URLs in the middle of a call? (Using Node)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'd like the following functionality with Twilio/Node: either

1. my server receives incoming call and the call rings on our custom client; at some point during the call (ideally can work before answering or after answering) or if no one answers on the client, the call is transferred to a webhook on a different server (my CRM provider) so the CRM can deal with it. OR
2. same as above, but the incoming call posts the incoming call request to both my server & my CRM webhook for the incoming call; I think this might not be possible though, not sure

I'm able to receive a Twilio call on my server without problem, and able to receive Twilio calls in my CRM without problem. However, when I tried to forward a call to the CRM after first receiving it on my custom server/client, it seems to always disconnect abrubtly. Pls help!

The code I'm using to update the call is below. The url works normally if sending the call directly to the CRM webhook. The CallSid is from my custom client from the incoming call

```
client.calls(req.body.CallSid)
.update({method: 'POST', url: 'https://crm.crmprovider.com/ctiapi/xml/cticall/twilio?authtoken=abc'})
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured out the proper way to do this. Should be using an "action" with "dial" and then checking "DialCallStatus" in the action endpoint and dealing with various statuses as appropriate. Sample code:

```
// On server, receive call. This is the url Twilio is 
// set to post webhook to when call comes in

app.post('/incomingCall', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  // Dial client first; after, call /callAction
  // I believe this will call /callAction if call is unanswered for 10 seconds or after a completed call or if there's no client open
  const dial = twiml.dial({timeout:10, action: '/callAction'});
  const client = 'whateverClientName'
  dial.client(client)
  res.type('text/xml')
  res.send(twiml.toString())
})

app.post('/callAction',(req,res)=>{
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  // Can set below if for other things like if call not completed, answered, or cancelled
  // In this example we say if call's not completed, route call to 3rd party site's webhook to further deal with the ongoing call
  if(req.body.DialCallStatus!=='completed'){
    twiml.redirect({method: 'POST'},'https://thirdpartywebhook.com/abc')}
  else {twiml.hangup()}
  res.type('text/xml')
  res.send(twiml.toString()) 
})
```

I didn't find Twilio docs super straightforward on this so hopefully this helps someone in the future!